# Reading a CSV file using Python

Tags: python, csv

please tell me what's the problem in this code it's giving an error

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Comment: what is the error ur getting?

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Without the error, or the contents of 'some.csv' it is difficult to help.

Comment: with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f                         showing syntax error as invalid syntax

Comment: the error given is some **basic information** you should give if you want to get an answer for a question like this.

Comment: sheesh, guys, some patience for a new user. If you don't have anything constructive to say, leave your jokes for the pub

Comment: @atul: Please copy and paste the output into your question.  Please **update** the question with the actual error message you're actually getting.  All of it.

Comment: I get the following error with your code: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'some.csv'`, not one that says `invalid syntax`. This means means it could not find the referenced .csv file. Is that your error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Answer (score 18):

Which version of Python are you using?

The `with` statement is new in 2.6 - if you're using 2.5 you need `from __future__ import with_statement`. If you use a Python older than 2.5 then there's no `with` statement, so just write:

```
import csv
f = open('some.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    print row
f.close()
```

It's really better to update to a modern version of Python, though. Python 2.5 was released almost 5 years ago, and the current version in the 2.x line is 2.7

Comment: @atul: Please do not bury important information in a comment.  Please **update** the question to contain **all** the facts.

Answer (score 6):

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

And if that doesn't work, rewrite it to not use `with` in the first place.