# Django Rest Framework import CSV to models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

is there any way to import csv file to django rest framework models?
Thank You in advance.

Comment: I don't know why you got negative vote. But there is no REST Framework option available, you can do this using custom / raw solution.

Comment: The app django-import-export does this easily for you in django admin and can probably be tied in to a serializers quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

Using python `csv` you can open/read/write/modify any csv file.
Using this method, you can parse your file and save it using DRF.

I wont post any code because its a general understanding question.
Good Luck.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

[Reading a CSV file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788521/reading-a-csv-file-using-python)